# Prove that there exist at most two parabolas passing through four given points.

Tags: determinant, conic-sections

> Prove that there exist at most two parabolas passing through four given points.

I recently get this:

If I have five points $(x_i,y_i),i=1,2,\ldots, 5$, I can represent the conic section by this determinant.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
  {1}&x&y&{xy}&{x^2}&{y^2} \\ 
  {1}&{x_1}&{y_1}&{x_1y_1}&{x_1^2}&{y_1^2} \\ 
  {1}&{x_2}&{y_2}&{x_2y_2}&{x_2^2}&{y_2^2} \\ 
  {1}&{x_3}&{y_3}&{x_3y_3}&{x_3^2}&{y_3^2} \\ 
  {1}&{x_4}&{y_4}&{x_4y_4}&{x_4^2}&{y_4^2} \\ 
  {1}&{x_5}&{y_5}&{x_5y_5}&{x_5^2}&{y_5^2} 
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$

So I think: if I have four points, in theory, I will get at most 2 parabolas. But what I only know is: for 
$$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+\cdots=0$$
$\Delta=B^2-AC=0$ means a parabola.

> Can I prove what I thought with this determinant?

Comment: See here:  http://mathpages.com/home/kmath546/kmath546.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here,I have a not so rigorous prove.
Consider this two curves that pass through four given points.

$$
T_1:A_1x^2+B_1 xy+C_1y^2+D_1x+E_1y+F_1=0\\
T_2:A_2x^2+B_2 xy+C_2y^2+D_2x+E_2y+F_2=0
$$

then we write it like this.

$$
(λ_1A_1+λ_2A_2)x^2+(λ_1B_1+λ_2B_2)xy+(λ_1C_1+λ_2C_2)y^2+⋯=0
$$

(since $Dx,Ey,F$ is unimportant to think about.)

apply $B^2-4AC=0$

$$(λ_1B_1+λ_2B_2)^2-4(λ_1A_1+λ_2A_2)(λ_1C_1+λ_2C_2)=0$$

expand it ,and we will get

$$\tag{1}(XX)λ_1^2+(YY)λ_1λ_2+(ZZ)λ_2^2=0$$

it's a Homogeneous equation.

At most it has two solutions. That is to say,we get 2 pairs of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$,so we get two parabolas.